# Using Fortran90 and MPI, new to both, trying to use MPI_Gather to collect from a loop 3 different variables in each process

Tags: math, fortran, mpi, fortran90, computation

I am new to both Fortran90 and MPI.  I have a loop that iterates different based on each individual process. Inside of that, I have a nested loop, and it is here that I make the computations that I desire along with the elements of the respective loops.  However, I want to send all of this data, the x, the y, and the computed values using x and y, to my root process, 0.  From here, I want to write all of the data to the same file in the format of 'x y computation'.

```
program fortranMPI
use mpi

!GLOBAL VARIABLE DECLARATION
real :: step = 0.5, x, y, comput
integer :: count = 0, finalCount = 5, outFile = 20, i   
!MPI 
integer :: ierr, myrank, mysize, status(MPI_STATUS_SIZE)

call MPI_INIT(ierr)
call MPI_COMM_RANK(MPI_COMM_WORLD,myrank,ierr)
call MPI_COMM_SIZE(MPI_COMM_WORLD,mysize,ierr)

if(myrank == 0) then
    !I want to gather my data here?
end if

do i = 1, mysize, 1
    if(myrank == i) then
        x = -2. + (myrank - 1.)*step
        do while (x<= 2.) 
            y= -2.
            do while (y<=2.)
                !Here is where I am trying to send my data!
                y = y + step
            end do
            x = x + (mysize-1)*(step)
        end do
    end if
end do
call MPI_FINALIZE(ierr)
end program fortranMPI
```

I keep getting stuck trying to pass the data! If someone could help me out, that would be great!  Sorry if this is simpler than I am making it, I am still trying to figure Fortran/MPI out.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: As I see, the loop with `i` index is useless. Also, the root process does not do any computation. So the `if(myrank == i) then` should be turn into `if(myrank /= 0) then`. Since no process received any data before the computation, you should gather data after the computation. The MPI_gather will be your friend. Use this comment to improve and if you need further help, respond to the comment.

Comment: @innoSPG thanks for the help.  Makes sense about the loop with the i index, shoulda seen that.  I tried using MPI_Gather:  

    `if(myrank == 0) then
        call MPI_GATHER(x, 1, MPI_REAL, xbuf, 1, MPI_REAL, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, ierr)
        open (unit=outFile,file="mandelbrotDynamic.txt",action="write",status="replace")
  write(outFile,*) xbuf
  close(outFile)
 end if`

However, this just gets stuck and never finishes. I simply wanted to test it with just gathering up 1 x value, but as I am new to MPI and Fortran, I may be doing this completely wrong.  Any help would be great!  Thanks!

Comment: `MPI_GATHER` is a collective operation, so all the process in the communicator must call it. And the master will receive the data from all processes.

Answer (score 0):

First of all the program seems to not have any sense on what its doing. If you can be more specific on what you want to do, i can help further.

Now, usually, before the calculations, this `if (myrank==0)` statement, is where you send your data on the rest of the processes. Since process 0 will be sending data, you have to add code right after that in order for the processes to receive the data. Also you may need to add an MPI_BARRIER (`call MPI_BARRIER`), right before the start of the calculations, just to make sure the data has reached every process.

As for the calculation part, you also have to decide, not only where you send data, but also where the data is received and if you also need any synchronization on the communication. This has to do with the design of your program so you are the one who knows what exactly you want to do.

The most common commands for sending and receiving data are `MPI_SEND` and `MPI_RECV`.

Those are *blocking* commands, which means that the communication should be synchronized. One Send command should be matched with one Receive command before both processes can continue. 
There are also non blocking commands, you can find them all here:
http://www.mpich.org/static/docs/v3.1/www3/

As for the `MPI_GATHER` command, this is used in order to gather data from a group of processes. This will only help you when you are going to use more than 2 processes to further accelerate your program. Except from that `MPI_GATHER` is used when you want to gather data and store them in an array fashion, and of course it's worth using only when you are going to receive lots of data which is definitely not your case here.

Finally about printing out results, i'm not sure if what you are asking is possible. Trying to open the same file handle using 2 processes, is probably going to lead to OS errors. Usually for printing out the results, you have rank 0 to do that, right after every other process has finished.

Comment: Thanks for the thoughts. Essentiallly I am trying to create a Mandelbrot bug, where process 0 collects the cooridnates (x and y), uses a function to count the Mandelbrot number, then passes x, y, and the count to process 0 to be written to a file.

`if(myrank == 0) then
      ! Recieves x, y, mandel count
end if
 
 do i = 1, mysize, 1
  if(myrank == i) then
   x = -2. + (myrank - 1.)*step
   do while (x<= 2.) 
    y= -2.
    do while (y<=2.)
     ! Sends x,y, mandel count to 0 
     y = y + step
    end do
    x = x + (mysize-1)*(step)
   end do
  end if
 end do
 call MPI_FINALIZE(ierr)`

Comment: This answer is more like a comment. When you need clarification to understand the question, please comment, otherwise you will get a lot of negative reputations that won't be good for you because you do not have enough for now.

Comment: I thought of that, but it would be quite a big comment, that's why i decided to post it as an answer. And in fact i think it answers to @jep9223 several questions, about how to send the data, and how to write the output. As for the rep, i don't give a single sh!t about them, i just want to help ppl.

Comment: @jep9223 if i understand this correctly, proc 1 does the actual calculations, and proc 0 simply writes the output. If this is the case, you don't even have to send the input data around. You simply need to send/receive the Mandel Count right after each calculation. I would recommend that you use separate if blocks for each process, and then coordinate the sends and the receives in order for the proc 0 to get the calculated result. Proc's 0 loop should just receive data and write to output. Proc's 1 loop should do the calculation and immediately send the results.

Comment: @GregK. Thanks for the advice.  I was able to collect all of the data to proc 0 using the send and recv.  Thanks!